# This numpy algorithm operating on integers occasionally returns floats, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, integer

This is part of an algorithm to generate concentric rings of points on a hexagonal lattice that I'm in the process of rewriting.

I'd thought it's all integer math, but I discovered that in some cases arrays are unexpectedly created as floats!

In the sequence below `p0` is a `float64` for `n=1` but `int64` for `n>1` and I simply can not figure out why this is happening.

I'm running numpy version 1.17.3, Anaconda installation of Python 3.7.3 on MacOS

```
import numpy as np
n_max = 3
for n in range(1, n_max+1):
    seq = np.arange(n, -n-1, -1, dtype=int)
    p0  = np.hstack((seq, (n-1)*[-n], seq[::-1], (n-1)*[n]))
    print('n: ', n)
    print('seq: ', seq)
    print('p0: ', p0.dtype, p0)
    print('')
```

returns

```
n:  1
seq:  [ 1  0 -1]
p0:  float64 [ 1.  0. -1. -1.  0.  1.]

n:  2
seq:  [ 2  1  0 -1 -2]
p0:  int64 [ 2  1  0 -1 -2 -2 -2 -1  0  1  2  2]

n:  3
seq:  [ 3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3]
p0:  int64 [ 3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -3 -3 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  3  3]
```

Is that *expected behavior?*

**update 1:** okay `np.hstack(([1, 0, -1], 1*[7]))` returns `int64` but `np.hstack(([1, 0, -1], 0*[7]))` returns `float64` so it's the occurrence of the `0*[n]` in the tuple on which `np.hstack` operates that's triggering the upcast to `float64`.

**update 2:** Just asked in Code Review: [Is there a better, cleaner or otherwise “less tricky” way to get these hexagonal arrays of dots arranged in this spiral pattern?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/241691/145009)

Comment: My own expectations would be that empty arrays don't have a contents type at all (unless we forced em to). Concatenating an empty array should not change the type.

Comment: @aka.nice agreed, that's what I'd expected, this was a real surprise!

Answer (score 2):

What's triggering the entire array to be cast to `np.float64`, is the empty list obtained when `n=0` with `(n-1)*[n]` and `(n-1)*[-n]`:

```
print((n-1)*[n])
# []
```

`np.hstack` constructs an array from each of its input arrays to be concatenated. For each array there's a call to [`np.atleast_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html), which by default casts empty arrays to `np.float64` dtype:

```
np.atleast_1d([])
# array([], dtype=float64)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that NumPy creates ndarrays from all inputs before concatenating them.

`[0]*n` evaluates to `[]`, which is an empty list and thus has no numeric type, therefore when being cast to an array it becomes an empty array with the default data type, [which is to use a float](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types).

You can avoid this by using casting the input to ndarrays yourself and specifying the datatype as int, for example like so:

```
import numpy as np
n_max = 3
for n in range(1, n_max+1):
    seq = np.arange(n, -n-1, -1, dtype=int)
    p0  = np.hstack((seq, np.array((n-1)*[-n], dtype=np.int32), seq[::-1], np.array((n-1)*[-n], dtype=np.int32)))
    print('n: ', n)
    print('seq: ', seq)
    print('p0: ', p0.dtype, p0)
    print('')
```

I can't really speak to whether it is expected behavior or not, but it does make some sense intrinsically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! pre-casting the arrays as int or (even worse) trapping the `n<1` case(s) both work.